# Get coordinates out of click to work with

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I've been trying to render some div instead of the context menu once the use user right-click anywhere on the page, and for this, I need to receive the coordinates of the click. Currently, I'm doing it like this

```
function printMousePos(event) {
  let coordinates = [event.clientX, event.clientY];
  //console.log(coordinates);
  return coordinates;
}

document.addEventListener("click", printMousePos);
```

In the console, I got an array with x and y, but I can't work with them outside the function. I've been trying something like

```
let a = function (event){...}
```

but it doesn't seem to return the array in any case, so how could I refer to x and y? The problem is that those are dynamic and change only when the event occurs. Should I just render the menu inside of the `printMousePos(event)`
? Or is there any other way to get x and y?

EDIT

Thanks a lot for your answers, works for me now. I did the following - rendered the menu outside everything, hide it using CSS, and on click it changes class to visible and appears in the coordinates of the click. Goes something like

rendering the menu in window =>

```
rootNode.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  //console.log('123');
  menu.classList.add('active');
  menu.style.top = `${event.clientY}px`;
  menu.style.left = `${event.clientX}px`;
});
```

and it shows on click. So, no need to get the coordinates outside.

Comment: How are you positioning the `<div>`?

Comment: You can't return anything from an event listener, the value is returned to the event queue, where the callback function was called. You can see it in the code, there's nothing in JS, which would receive the return value. Use an outer scope variable instead, or as you said, "_render the menu inside of the [event handler]_".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Teemu said "You can't return anything from an event listener". And you don't need to.

You can either declare the coordinates array outside the event listener and fill it with data once the event fired OR (and I'd prefer that) write the function that is supposed to work with the coordinates and then call it inside the event listener (which is pretty much what you suggested yourself):

```
function handleClick(x,y) {
    // do stuff with x and y here, like drawing a div...
}

document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    handleClick(event.clientX, event.clientY);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works for me now. I did the following - rendered the menu outside everything, hide it using CSS, and on click it changes class to visible and appears in the coordinates of the click. Goes something like ```